# Make expression match optional value if possible

Tags: regex, jmeter, perl

Consider the following text that might be part of an HTTP response from jMeter:

```
<menu id="Alpha" name="alpha">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c" selected="selected">C</option>
</menu>

<menu id="Bravo" name="bravo">
    <option value="d">D</option>
    <option value="e">E</option>
</menu>
```

I'm trying to extract the ID of each menu, as well as the selected option's value if there is an option selected. If there is no option selected, then by default, the first option's value should be matched. For example, in this example, I want the following to be matched:

```
"Alpha" "c"
"Bravo" "d"
```

So far, I have written the following:

```
<select id="Form:parameterList:([^"]+?)".*?>.*?(?:<option value="([^"]*?)".*?(?:selected="selected")?>)?.*?</select>
```

The problem with this is that only the first option's value is ever matched, and the selected option is never matched. That is, I want to prioritize matching the optional pattern.

Thanks,
Victor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider how maintainable your script will be using that complex regex.

You can achieve the result you desire using xpath extractors, conditional/loop controllers and or post-processors...

First get a list of all ids:

```
//menu/@id
```

You can get a list of ids containing an option with attribute selected = 'selected' with something similar to:

```
//menu/@id[/option[@selected='selected']]
```

Iterate through the first list (in a beanshell processor or loop controller, for instance). Where an id appears in the second list, extract the selected value with:

```
//menu[@id='xxxx']/option[@selected='selected']/@value  /*substitue xxxx with appropriate id*/
```

Where the id does not have a 'selected' value, extract the default value:

```
//menu/[@id='xxxx']/option[1]/@value  /*substitue xxxx with appropriate id*/
```

(sorry if my xpath aren't completely accurate, I have written this from memory alone, but hopefully the breadcrumbs are there to follow)

Comment: As a note, the second one should be

    `//menu[option/@selected="selected"]/@id`

Otherwise, thanks!